# Hibernate constraint violation exception hangs sql server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I am trying to save a set of records into db like shown below. I have set unique constraint on 2 columns of the table. I have handled the constraint exception. If I insert new set of records I have no issues. If I try to insert duplicate records, exception is handled but ms sql server says

> executing query. waiting for response from data source.

Also after this if I try to insert new set of records the http request is not completed and the records are not inserted. How should I handle constraint exception so that ms sql server does not hang?

```
public void addStepFlow(List<StepFlow> stepFlows) {

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        for (StepFlow stepFlow : stepFlows) {

            session.save(stepFlow);

            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        } catch (JDBCException e) {
            SQLException cause = (SQLException) e.getCause();
            System.out.println(cause.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you do a batch insert instead of one by one?

Comment: Just started learning. Don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rollback on exception.. and also close the session no matter what heppens:

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    for (StepFlow stepFlow : stepFlows) {

        session.save(stepFlow);

        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
    tx.commit();

    } catch (JDBCException e) {
        SQLException cause = (SQLException) e.getCause();
        System.out.println(cause.getMessage());

        tx.rollback();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: yes the tx has to be defined before try block.. try my update

Comment: Yes i forgot in tension. did it

Comment: Great. Glad i could help